# Passing value from one method to another without passing value using parameter in Method signature

Tags: apex

I am facing a basic problem with value passing accross functions..Can someone advise me the correct syntax?

```
// source method where from "Id1" value is generated
Method1() {
    Id1= (select id from objA);
}

Method2() {
    //I need to use "Id1" here.
    // pls suggest the syntax
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why you want to do it, but as method local variables are scoped to the method they are declared in, you'll need to store it in a class scoped variable if you want to cross the method scope.

```
private ID temIDholder;

Method1() // source method where from "Id1" value is generated
 {
  Id1= (select id from objA);
temIDholder = Id1;
  }

 Method2(){
     //I need to use "Id1" here.
     // pls suggest the syntax
     x = temIDholder ;
  }
```

**But, this is not a very secure or maintainable way to write code**. Other developers may use Method2 without realizing the hidden dependency, introducing a bug or point of failure. If you truly want to do this, you better add some error handling.

```
Method2()
     {
         //I need to use "Id1" here.
         // pls suggest the syntax
     if( temIDholder==null){
          //throw error (or assign a default value for datatypes where this is possible)
      }
      x = temIDholder ;
}
```

Comment: I have 3 buttons in the page ..namely clone, save and submit..when I am clicking on clone the old records sf id and new records sf ids are generated . ..then when I am clicking on save I need to do some validation using the old & cloned objects sf id..I do not have the scope of passing values accross clone's action and submit's action method.thst is why I was searching for an alternative way.

Comment: Could have helped if you added those details to your question. But yes, the general idea is to store such data as class variables or properties, and then use methods to execute logic on the data stored by(in) your class object.